# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk vs EC2 instance with docker containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I understand correctly, Elastic Beanstalk creates an EC2 instance for each application you deploy. However, an application typically doesn't run at 100% CPU, yet amazon charges you per instance used. So if I deployed 5 apps with Dockerfiles, AWS would charge the usage of 5 EC2 instances per month.

With this in mind, can't I just simply launch an EC2, install docker and run my containers in there? Wouldn't that be much more cost-effective?

Comment: There's a new container service that's much more tailored to docker apps.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloud-container-management/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AWS has integrated Elastic Beanstalk (EB) with the EC2 Container Service (ECS) to support [multi-container Docker environments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html). An EB environment composed of multiple instances in an autoscaling group can run multiple containers per instance, managed through the ECS agent and its API. Use `.ebextensions` to map multiple ELB listeners to the containers running on EC2 instances.

See [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecstutorial.html) for running an Nginx + PHP-FPM in separate containers.

Thanks @Synturas for tipping me off to this update.

Comment: Thanks Ben! Your blog post is a very interesting read (actually I got stuck on your website reading all the other stuff as well ;) I didn't expect such severe limitations of Beanstalk, for now I am going to go ahead and just run Docker containers inside a small EC2 instance. I'm curious how well that will run.

Comment: What if you were just running ONE high-load application that just ran on a single container and connected to an RDS database. In that scenario, would you just run a single docker instance, or a multiple-container docker instance to somehow maximize resources?

Answer (score 2):

Yes your assumptions are correct. The difference is that for doing it on EC2 you will have to manage and monitor your containers all by yourself. So I guess for production environments you'll have to have your own team for that, or else go with BeanStalk.

Also better follow this [Docker on Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html) documentation.

## Edit

*Thanks for the comment @sajithp  I have updated the link*

Comment: Mentioned link is broken. Just sharing new links :)
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html